# No results returned by SimpleJdbcCall that executes Oracle function returning a REF CURSOR

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc, sql-function, ref-cursor

Here is what I have:

**Function Specification:**

```
FUNCTION GET_SOME_DATA RETURNS REF CURSOR 
IN_LOOK_UP_PARAM VARCHAR2 IN
```

**Java Code Snippet:**

```
    SimpleJdbcCall call =
        new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withCatalogName(SP_PACKAGE_NAME)
            .withFunctionName("GET_SOME_DATA")
            .declareParameters(
                new SqlOutParameter(
                    SP_OUT_PARAM_RESULTS, 
                    OracleTypes.CURSOR, 
                    HEADER_ROW_MAPPER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter(SP_IN_PARAM, Types.VARCHAR))
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
            .withReturnValue()
            .returningResultSet(SP_OUT_PARAM_RESULTS, HEADER_ROW_MAPPER);
    call.setFunction(true);
    call.compile();
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = call.execute(
        new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(SP_IN_PARAM, lookupId));
```

The row mapper method is not called resultMap contains the `SP_OUT_PARAM_RESULTS` key with value as null.

When tried to debug this, at some point after procedure execution in Spring library code, the update count is returned as -1 and so the code path where row mapper is called, is skipped.

Any idea what I might be doing incorrectly in any of the oracle function/Simple Jdbc call?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything that would not make that code work. Your function specification looks incomplete though - do you have the complete statement for creating the function?

Try with this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CURSOR_DEMO (p_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
IS
  p_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  open p_cursor FOR SELECT p_in AS P1 FROM DUAL;
  RETURN p_cursor;
END CURSOR_DEMO;
```

using this SimpleJdbcCall:

```
    SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withFunctionName("CURSOR_DEMO")
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlOutParameter("RESULTS", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new ColumnMapRowMapper()),
                    new SqlParameter("P_IN", Types.VARCHAR))
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
    SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("P_IN", "TEST");
    Map<String, Object> results = call.execute(params);
    System.out.println(results);
```